# I got an error messeage while opening Dynamics NAV page

Tags: dynamics-nav

After creating one new company I am getting this error. Please anyone tell me hoew to resolve this.

> Could not open the '' company. Your program license permits a maximum
>   of 2 non-demonstration companies. Contact your system administrator to
>   set up additional companies

.

Comment: You need to upload proper license to database or server.

Comment: It sounds like you have the default license, the steps to update the license for your company are going to be different for the various versions of NAV, and oddly enough the type of license you have too.  A start would be to include the version of NAV are running.

Comment: Thank you Mak and Akedren for your support. i solved that issue by create new instance of NAV  server .

Comment: @Manik This confuses me: this is a license error. The NAV Server gets the license from the database. So adding NAV servers shouldn't do anything. Sounds like you did something else...